# Section referencing disabled by \renewcommand

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

The sections in my article have to be re-styled as follows :

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\medskip \addtocounter{section}{1}\flushleft 
\textbf{\Roman{section}. \ #1}\medskip \setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}}
```

However, I am unable to refer to my sections using `\label` and `\ref` commands. Referencing works fine is the above code is commented out. What could be the issue?

edit: The referencing needs to be in Roman too.

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter{section}` (this should automatically reset `subsection`. Also, `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}` should be used for a consistent setting and referencing of sectional numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using

```
\addtocounter{section}{1}
```

use

```
\refstepcounter{section}
```

This increments the section counter by 1 and tells latex that the next reference created by `\label{...}` should refer to this counter.

Also, if you want the second numbers to always be in `\Roman` then you should use:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

So now your section command becomes:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\medskip\refstepcounter{section}{1}%
       \flushleft\thesection. \ #1}\medskip%
       \setcounter{subsection}{0}\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}}
```

If, instead, you wanted `\ref{...}` to produce `\thesection. \ #1` then this is more complicated as you have to set `@currentlabel` and `@` is a protected character. For this you would need:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\medskip\refstepcounter{section}{1}%
       \flushleft\thesection. \space #1}\medskip%
       \def\@currentlabel{\thesection. \space #1}
       \setcounter{subsection}{0}\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}}
\makeatletter
```

Btw, rather than restyling your section titles "by hand", you might find it easier to use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Comment: That introduces the references, but they should be in \Roman font..

Comment: Take a look at the titlesec package.

Comment: @Aradnix Look at the last line of my post!

Comment: @ManojKumar If you want them in `\Roman` then you should use `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}`. If you want the reference to be the value of `\Roman{section}. \ #1` then edit your question to say this and I'll modify my answer to say how to do this.

Comment: I saw your answer Andrew that's why I told @ManojKumar to check the package.

Comment: @Andrew : I have edited my question

Comment: @ManojKumar I have edited my answer!